# Python не выводит итог замены

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не выводит итоги шифровки. Скорее всего накосячил в выборе рандомных символов в symbolsCrypt. Подскажите, как правильно сделать. А лучше еще как записать этот получившийся рандом в файл и использовать его для дешифровки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  import random
    symbolsAlpha = [chr(x) for x in range(1,208)]
symbolsCrypt = [chr(random.randrange(1,208))]

cryptMode = input("[Ш]ифровка|[Д]ешифровка: ").upper()
if cryptMode not in ['Ш','Д']:
    print("Ошибка: метод не найден!"); raise SystemExit
startMessage = input("Write the message: ").upper()
keys = dict(zip(symbolsAlpha,symbolsCrypt))

def encryptDecrypt(mode, message, final = ""):
    if mode == 'Ш':
        for symbol in message:
            if symbol in keys: final += keys[symbol]
    else:
    for symbol in message:
        for key in keys:
            if symbol == keys[key]: final += key
    return final
print("Final message:",encryptDecrypt(cryptMode, startMessage))
```

Comment: Какие символы входят в диапазон 1-208? И вообще как всегда: если что-то работает не так как ожидается, выводи на печать промежуточные значения.

Comment: ftp://ftp.vt.tpu.ru/study/Malchukov/public/PHDL/Projects/ascii.pdf

Comment: Почему вы решили, что содержимое этой ссылки имеет какое-то отношение к питону? Кроме того, русские символы не относятся и никогда не относились к ASCII